# How do I optimize this extremely simple MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am using MySQL 5.7 (can't change this), and I am kind of new to MySQL. I have a fair amount of experience with SQL sever so just trying to work through some of these quirks.

The query I want to run is

```
select *
from temp_main_working t
  left outer join temp_sf s on t.PM_ORDER_ID = s.pm_order_id
where s.pm_order_id is null
```

The explain looks like this

[image]

If I change the outer join to an inner join (which obviously won't give me what I want), as such

```
select *
from temp_main_working t
  inner join temp_sf s on t.PM_ORDER_ID = s.pm_order_id
```

I get an explain that looks like this

[image]

which is obviously much better for performance.

In other cases where i use a left join, it managed to use associated indexes just fine. What is going on here? How do I get it to run efficiently?

**UPDATE**

Including explain for Akina's suggested query

[image]

Comment: Edit the question and add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: The problem has already been solved, I will edit the question to include the answer

Comment: If you have a solution, please provide it in an answer, not in the question. And it would still be good to edit the question with the information I asked. Performance depends on many things like indexes available, column types, table engines. We don't know if the tables are using InnoDB, MyISAM, Memory engine or somethign else. We don't know if they are temporary or not. We don't know their sizes. All that would be useful  in order to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT t.*
FROM temp_main_working t
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM temp_sf s 
                   WHERE t.pm_order_id = s.pm_order_id )
```

**UPDATE**

```
id select_type        table partitions type   possible_keys key     key_len ref                rows filtered Extra
1  PRIMARY            t     null       index  null          PRIMARY 4       null               1    100      Using where; Using index
2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY s     null       eq_ref PRIMARY       PRIMARY 4       test.t.pm_order_id 1    100      Using index
```

Comment: I get pretty much the same explain. The only change is 'select_type' is no 'DEPENDENT SUBQUERY'.

Comment: @ChechyLevas *I get pretty much the same explain.* 1) The execution plan is dependent by data statistics. And it can change if the statistics change. 2) Efficiency is related to execution time and/or resource usage, not execution plan beauty.

Comment: My original query runs for over 5 minutes without returning and I let yours run fir 40 seconds before killing. This question is as much about the theoretical background/general solution as it is about the practical solution to this specific problem, so your comment on statistics is well received (I did not know this). In any case, both queries take longer than I think they should, and the execution plan seems to be the best clue as to why.

Comment: @ChechyLevas EXPLAIN added. Look Extra.

Comment: I added the explain from my system to compare to yours. I also discovered the problem: The datatypes on the join columns are not the same. One is a decimal and the other is a varchar (I didn't make one of these tables and assumed that it would be the same as the source data). Anyway, good to know that type differences on a join could result in poor performance.

Comment: @ChechyLevas *The datatypes on the join columns are not the same.* Correct this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because the datatypes on the join columns are not the same. Changing the types to match solves the problem completely.